# How can I check the type of material ui theme in react js? (light or dark)

Tags: reactjs, types, material-ui, themes

I want to create certain conditions based on whether the type of material ui theme is light or dark
How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to recreate the theme and update the value [`theme.palette.type`](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#dark-mode) (`'light'` or `'dark'`) and pass it to the `ThemeProvider` to apply the change.

```js
const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light"
  }
});

function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(defaultTheme);
  const onClick = () => {
    const isDark = theme.palette.type === "dark";
    setTheme(
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          type: isDark ? "light" : "dark"
        }
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Card>
        <Typography variant="h3">{theme.palette.type}</Typography>
        <Button onClick={onClick}>Toggle theme</Button>
      </Card>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

You can then check the theme type in children components using either hook or HOC

#### Hook

```js
const isDarkTheme = useTheme().palette.type === 'dark';
```

#### HOC

```js
const ThemedComponent = withTheme(Component)
```

```js
render() {
  const isDarkTheme = this.props.theme.palette.type === 'dark';
  return (...)
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64557510/how-can-i-check-the-type-of-material-ui-theme-in-react-js-light-or-dark]

Answer (score 9):

The following does not work anymore:

```
const isDarkTheme = useTheme().palette.type === 'dark';
```

Try this Instead:

```
 const isDarkTheme = useTheme().palette.mode === 'dark';
```

Comment: Checking the mode works for me, thank you